# Do you know any Spanish-English IT Dictionary?

Tags: language, dictionary

fellas. Don't know is this question belongs here, but anyway.

I'm in the need of a Spanish-English IT Dictionary that you can access or download from the Internet for free. My studentes are going to present a final project in their class in English and they need such a dictionary to master the correct meanings of some IT terms. Do you know something like that? I prefer it having the spanish meaning/word next to the English one.

Thankyou very much.

Comment: It doesn't belong here.  Requests for hardware, product, and learning material recommendations are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-spanish-english-dictionary/id321568349?mt=8

The leading Free Spanish English Dictionary for iPhone, iPad & iPod Touch ❥ Over 32,000 Offline Translations & Usage Examples ❥ Audio Pronunciation ❥ 1,559 Conjugated Verbs ❥ Phrasebook ❥ Vocabulary Quizzes ❥ Universal Application

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.langtolang.englishspanish&hl=en

Langtolang Free English Spanish And Spanish English Dictionary with online lookup.
It gives suggestions if you spell a word wrong. You can easily change the languages.

from a simple google search.